# How can I pass through text from an rlogin console to local vim in cygwin?

Tags: unix, vim, cygwin

I have a cygwin console running on my windows box, and vim installed and working fine. But when I do an rloging to a server (rlogin server.at.com running unix) my vim command is launching the vi on my remote box. Is there a way to tell cygwin to "tunnel" the text file that I try to open in the rlogin session to a local vim session just as it does with a local file (applies also to my nedit which I dont have in the remote machine but I do in the local one)?

Thanks!

Comment: That kinda defeats the purpose of rlogin. RFC 1282 defines rlogin as "a remote-echoed, locally flow-controlled virtual terminal with proper flushing of output." For file transfer, try sftp or scp.

That said, you should probably be using ssh anyway. rlogin is insecure.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how or if it would work with rlogin but [bcvi](http://sshmenu.sourceforge.net/articles/bcvi/) is SSH-based and allows you to do `$ vim filename` on the server and open a GVim window on your local machine.

You can also use Vim's default plugin `netrw` which lets you manage and edit remote files using, among other protocols, `rcp`:

```
" manage files
:e rcp://[username@]machinename/path/to/directory/

" edit file
:e rcp://[username@]machinename/path/to/directory/filename
```

But… is there a reason for using `rlogin` instead of `ssh`?

Comment: I guess there must be, server refuses all ssh connections but always allows with rlogin.

Comment: `rlogin`, `rcp` and friends are widely considered insecure. If you have an idea of the name of the admin in charge of this machine you should ask him to do something.